# Validator minLength FormGroup Reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am trying to validate a `minLength` but it does not recognize it, for that I am using a function. I have also tried it directly in the template but I do not get any results.

myComponent.html

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Ingresa tu celular" type="number" formControlName="celular">
    <mat-error *ngIf="forma.controls['celular'].invalid">{{ errorCelular() }}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
```

myComponent.ts

```
celular: [ '', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(9)] ],


errorCelular() {
return this.forma.controls.celular.hasError('required') ? 'El celular es necesario.' :
this.forma.controls.celular.hasError('minlength')? 'Mínimo 9 caracteres': '';
}
```

Comment: Can you show the whole form?

Comment: is the required working.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`minLength` doesn't work in previous versions of angular with `type="number"`. Check [this Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15053) why.

If you do not need the input to be of `type="number"`, change it to `type="text"` and it should work. If you need it to be of type number, then you should use a custom Validator which checks that the number is greater than the minimum 9 digit number (100000000)

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

function customMinValidator(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {

    if (control.value !== undefined && (isNaN(control.value) || control.value >= 100000000 )) {
        return { 'customMin': true };
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then use it like -
`celular: [ '', [Validators.required, customMinValidator] ]`

Note: The above is just an example on "how" to use it. It won't work exactly as expected as the condition would fail for a number like 000112313, which has a minLength of 9 as desired. But this should give you a fair idea on how to tackle it.

Comment: This is a big help, I did not know that minLength did not work with type number. In effect if I change it to type text if it works but I need it to be a number. I'm going to try that function and try to implement it.